# Finding Transition states from Saddle points

Tags: computational-physics, physical-chemistry

I have a set of saddle points of molecule with corresponding energy values. I would like to find the transition state of the molecule. I understand that transition state is the first-order saddle point. But I have a problem on realizing the definition to the real problem.

My question is: How do I select the particular saddle point to be a transition state? Is the structure corresponding highest energy a transition state?

I appreciate your answer.

Thank you.

ps: molecule has rotational transition state

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, then you need to plot a path from the initial to the final conditions, optimize that path so that it doesn't go higher up in energy than it needs to, and then take the highest saddle point it passes as the transition state.

That is, you take the highest saddle point, but you need to make sure that it's actually necessary to pass through that state for the reaction you want to describe. Thus, for example, you wouldn't count the Transition Structure B in the image below as the transition state for reaction A, or vice versa.

[image]

<sup>[Image source](https://voer.edu.vn/m/exploring-potential-energy-surface/4823f4fa)</sup>